# Add In crash when adding comment

Tags: ms-word, vsto

OK, so this is really strange...

I have a VSTO add in for Word, that searches for text and adds comments.
Everything works great, except for a very specific comment, that when added, Word crashes.

Please note this is not a regular exception that can be caught - the whole app just crashes down with the "Microsoft Word has stopped working" title.

This is the line of code that crashes word:

```
var comment = document.Comments.Add(range, ref commentText);
```

What can cause a crash when the code adds comment? And why does it happen only for a specific comment?

thanks!

Comment: Can you share the code and the text of the specific comment that crashes the add-in?

Comment: What code do you use for adding comments? What line of code exactly crashes Word?